# How do I resolve "No views were found in assemblies or could be generated for Table"?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, asp.net-web-api

I am working with a database first model in Entity Framework 5 and when I attempt to add a row, I get the following error:
"No views were found in assemblies or could be generated for Table 'ui_renewals'."

The table exists in my EDMX and the template generated a ui_renewals class. I've deleted the table from the EDMX and added it again using the Update Model from Database option and I get the same error. Creating a separate connection for it resolves the issue, but that seems like a less-than-ideal solution (more like a kludge) not to mention it makes it more difficult to maintain in the future.

Any ideas on how to fix this so that I can add or update (I've tried both) a row in ui_renewals?

Here is the code I'm currently using - only difference before was using db as a DBContext instead of ui (yes, receipt is misspelled - gotta love legacy stuff)

```
        [HttpPost]
    public bool UpdateTeacher(string login_id, string password, UIRenewal data)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // map from UIRenewal VM to ui_renewal
            ui_renewals Renewal = Mapper.Map<UIRenewal, ui_renewals>(data);
            // check to see if this is a new entry or not
            var tmp = ui.ui_renewals.Find(Renewal.reciept);
            if (tmp == null)
                ui.ui_renewals.Add(Renewal);
            else
            {
                // mark as modified
                db.Entry(Renewal).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            // save it
            try
            {
                ui.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DBConcurrencyException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I should mention that I do have a view in the model (v_recent_license).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a very old question, however as I haven't found any other topics like this, I'll post my answer.

I have had the same Exception thrown. I found that, in a failed attempt to optimize EF performance, following the advices found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853), I left behind this piece of code in EF .edmx code-behind:

```
<EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="XXXModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="YYYEntities" GenerateUpdateViews="false">
```

I removed the `GenerateUpdateViews="false"` string, and all is working again.

(The Exception message is a little misleading in my opinion).

Comment: that's exactly what it was. It had helped (slightly) on startup and debug times, so it did what it was supposed to but I had forgotten to take it out when we were told we needed to update that table!

Comment: I didn't do any optimizations, but this was set false anyway.  Setting to true fixed it for me.